# Is it possible to use Gmail Android app without SSL?

Tags: gmail

I'm interested on using my email without SSL on my Android phone, yet I haven't been able to find the option to do it or to load the emails server without SSL.

I want to be sure it's not possible before giving up. Is it possible to use the Gmail app without SSL on Android?

Answer (score 3):

Gmail has been [HTTPS only](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2014/03/staying-at-forefront-of-email-security.html) since early 2014. Even if plaintext connections *were* still supported, it would be insecure. Gmail has fully supported HTTPS since it launched, so there was really never a reason to disable it anyway.